# Create a class that takes a matrix for instantiation

Tags: python, matrix, instantiation

I'm asked to create a class that that takes an m by n array for instantiation. Then give the class a method which does any operation on the matrix, lets say doubles its diagonal entries and returns it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from this simple skeleton:

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        self.matrix = matrix

    def double_diagnonal_entries(self):
        # do calcs
        return self.matrix
```

Note, that if you need to implement some basic matrix ops like addition you might consider operator overloading such as:

```
def __add__(self, another_matrix):
    # do the math
    return sum_matrix
```